# Switch from HTTP to HTTPS with Apache2 not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, apache-http-server

I'm trying to change my existing apache2 site from http to https with a self-signed cert on Ubuntu 11. The site is currently running with the config at `sites-available/default`. I've followed the documentation in `/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz` which basically says install the `ssl-cert` package (it was already installed, so I ran `sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite` to be sure) and then do:

```
sudo a2dissite default
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

I updated the `sites-available/default-ssl` so that `DocumentRoot` points to `/var/siteX.mydomain.com`.
I then ran:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But my requests to the http version are still succeeding and being served. Requests to the https version just hang indefinitely. What did I miss?

**Edit:**
FWIW, There are 6 other sites being served by apache2 on this box, in addition to the site that I'm having trouble with. So my `sites-enabled` directory looks like:

```
default-ssl (symlink to sites-available/default-ssl - maps to siteX.mydomain.com)
siteA.mydomain.com
siteB.mydomain.com
siteC.mydomain.com
siteD.mydomain.com
siteE.mydomain.com
siteF.mydomain.com
```

In the other site[A-F].mydomain.com sites, there is no reference to siteX.mydomain.com anywhere, so none of them have been accidentally configured to keep serving traffic to http://siteX.mydomain.com

**Edit2:**
Here's a snippet from the beginning of my `000-default-ssl` config file (everything after this is just the default stuff that I didn't touch):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName siteX.mydomain.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/siteX.mydomain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

**Edit3:**
Updating with output of `grep -v \# 000-default-ssl | grep -Ev '^[ \t]*$'`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName siteX.mydomain.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/siteX.mydomain.com

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/siteX.mydomain.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Options +ExecCGI
            AddHandler cgi-script .pl
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Edit4:**
This is the contents of `ports.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443  # I just added this now - still not working !!
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you configured any additional sites beyond the "default"?

Comment: Yes, theres 5 or 6 other enabled sites with their respective config files at e.g. sites-enabled/sub.domain.com

Comment: Check your `httpd.conf`. Should have a `Listen` at port `80`. Comment it out (add `#` at the begining). Also, check your default-ssl to load before the other sites. Rename it as `000-default-ssl` and the others to 001, 002, etc.

Comment: Is it safe to just rename the config files for each site? Is there anything else that needs to be done if I do that? But even if I do prioritize the default-ssl config, why would that matter? There's no other config in that directory that references the site I'm having trouble with, so there should be no conflict. The `a2dissite default` command disabled the http site/config. Also, my `http.conf` is completely empty.

Comment: delete the symlink on `sites-enabled`, rename `default-ssl` to `000-default-ssl` on `sites-available` and `sudo a2ensite 000-default-ssl`. Restart apache and test again

Comment: I did exactly as you recommended (and reloaded plus restarted apache2), but it's still exactly the same unfortunately. HTTP requests succeed and HTTPS requests hang indefinitely. I don't understand - the HTTPS requests not working would be one thing, but how is the HTTP version still active. I'll post some of my 000-default-ssl config

Comment: Be sure you aren't getting any cached results use incognito mode or clear your cache out.  Is this running on Windows or Linux? If the latter you can use nmap localhost, to see what ports are open or use netstat -tulnp, this will list the processes and ports bound.

Comment: Incognito mode in Chrome still produces the same result. It's a Linux box. Both those commands show ports 80 and 443 open and listening for connections. But the other sites that apache is serving are configured for http:80 - the site I'm having trouble with is the only site configured for https:443

Comment: Did you check for `Listen` on your config files? There is usually a `Listen 80` at `httpd.conf`. Comment that out. Also, do a `grep -v \# /path/to/000-default-ssl | grep -Ev ^[ \t]*$'` and paste it if possible

Comment: `httpd.conf` is completely empty. Post is updated with command output.

Comment: Do a `grep -r Listen /path/to/config/folder`. It MUST match at least once (probably with `80` as port). Make sure to disable any `Listen` on port `80` and add a `Listen 443` instead **if missing** (could be on modules folder as `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>Listen 443</IfModule>`)

Comment: I found `Listen` in `ports.conf` (post is updated).  I tried adding `NameVirtualHost *:443` to the `IfModule mod_ssl.c` conditional and also changing `VirtualHost _default_:443` in `000-default-ssl` to `VirtualHost *:443`. Still not working. Is it safe to remove the `Listen *:80` given that other sites are being served over HTTP?

Comment: Please, check `error_log` for issues with the certificate. As for to leave or not the `80` port, I undertood that you intented to change all your webs to be under HTTPS. If you only intented a single site, leave the 80 port.